# Is there a lightweight signal in WinAPI / C++ on Windows 7?

Tags: c++, winapi

For a lightweight signal between threads on Windows, [`WaitOnAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706898(v=vs.85).aspx) is the ideal tool starting from Windows 8. I have to support Windows 7 for the time being, and the best improvement I found (both searching around and reading MSDN) over a Win32 API Event is to go with [`SleepConditionVariableCS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleepconditionvariablecs).

Here is a minimal example (handle <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in a console app):

```cpp
//HANDLE Signal;  // event
CONDITION_VARIABLE Signal;
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD ctl){
  switch (ctl) {
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:  /*SetEvent(Signal);*/ WakeConditionVariable(&Signal); return TRUE;
    default:            return FALSE; // pass it to the system
  }
}

int main(){

  //Signal = CreateEventA(NULL, TRUE /*manual-reset event*/, 
  //                       FALSE/*initial nonsignaled*/, "ctrl-c_sig023xgyI8");
  InitializeConditionVariable(&Signal);  InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
  
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlHandler, TRUE) // register CtrlHandler with the system
  // auto hThread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, worker, nullptr, ..);
  
  //WaitForSingleObject(Signal, INFINITE);
  EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    SleepConditionVariableCS (&Signal, &cs, INFINITE);
  LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
  // stop thread, cleanup, CloseHandle(hThread); CloseHandle(Signal);

  return 0;
}
```

This example forces the "signal" use-case : the system starts a dedicated thread just to run your `CtrlHandler` (when the user enters <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>) which gets a chance then to signal the `main` thread for user-requested stop.

Is there a better (lighter) approach in the Win32 API or C++ (knowing that, of course, C++ has to ultimately go through the Win32 API).

Comment: There is always `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable`, which probably does much the same as the code you have there.  Why is 'lightweight' such a pressing problem?  I doubt this approach uses a great deal of system resources.

Comment: In this minimal example, you could invent your own undebugged synchronization mechanism and probably wouldn't see a performance difference. "Lightweight" matters in real critical code (unfit for SO small examples). But I'll admit there is an academic aspect to it also.

Comment: I would use the features for this that you'll find in the C++ standard library. Perform profiling before trying to use these platform specific functions to make it more lightweight. Most of the time, the thing in the standard library is just a wrapper around a set of platform specific functions, packaged in a neat way to make them easy to use (and supports RAII all the way).

Comment: @Ted : you had to say it ! To be honest, I'm expecting no answer/"that's the lightest there is", and so I'll end up profiling anyway (but hey, you never know !). But I was more thinking about comparing Event/SleepConditionVariableCS/SleepConditionVariableSRW. You think C++ can do better ? It has to go through WinApi, and it can't possibly do less than a single call to the API like I do (OK, maybe two with the Wake function).

Comment: @WasfiJAOUAD I'm expecting those writing the standard library for a certain platform to do a decent job of not bloating object wrappers or slowing down the interaction with the underlying API.   I do not expect things to be faster when using the C++ library but easier (a lot less code) and safer (RAII) - and I also expect these wrappers to be well tested, which is hard when it comes to threading.

Comment: @Ted : I totally agree (basically what Paul said in a more practical way in his "reasonable" comment). But we're not talking about best possible raw performance anymore (which is rarely needed, but that's what I'm asking here).

Comment: @WasfiJAOUAD Then, what except raw performance would be a good reason?

Comment: @Ted : what you mention : outside of a situation where best possible perf. is priority #1 (1% of code ? not even), I'm more than happy to use a "reasonably fast" API/Lib made by mature developers who care about bloat/RAII/thread safety/readability/.. I do care about those too. Here I'm asking about the 1%. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: A "reasonably fast" API is not always the really fast API before benchmarking. Also, it's not an optimization option to choose a really fast API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a complaint way, you can have Event or Semaphore object, backed by an atomic, with possible spinning. You'll have the part of lightweight-ness of `WaitOnAddress` that comes from the userspace ops. You still won't save an OS object though.

---

If you're fine with a hacky way, that is against the documentation and is not future-proof, then
`SRWLOCK` is known to behave as a binary semaphore, implying that it can be released not in acquired thread. There's AppVerifier check for that, but still this currently works with this check disabled.

See [Can SRW Lock be used as a binary semaphore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62614716/can-srw-lock-be-used-as-a-binary-semaphore)

So,

```cpp
SRWLOCK lock = SRWLOCK_INIT;

BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD ctl){
  switch (ctl) {
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:  ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&lock); return TRUE;
    default:            return FALSE; // pass it to the system
  }
}

int main(){

  //Signal = CreateEventA(NULL, TRUE /*manual-reset event*/, 
  //                       FALSE/*initial nonsignaled*/, "ctrl-c_sig023xgyI8");

  AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&lock);

 
  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(CtrlHandler, TRUE) // register CtrlHandler with the system
  // auto hThread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, worker, nullptr, ..);
  
  AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&lock); // again, will be acquired when released in `CtrlHandler`

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Live and learn. I was saying C++ has better syntax, but this actually puts WinAPI back on the map! I still would go with C++ (nicer & safer). But I wouldn't hesitate to use this "hack" for a small gadget/if other developers won't interact with my code. It's not a hack when you know for a fact that the OS won't move anymore (my question is about Win7 specifically) !

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there is faster than `SleepConditionVariableCS/SRW`.

And no much difference between these. This shows a slight advantage to `SRW` (~2%) on my CPU :

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv){

  CONDITION_VARIABLE cv; InitializeConditionVariable(&cv);
  
  //SRWLOCK Signal; InitializeSRWLock(&Signal);
  CRITICAL_SECTION cs; InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
  //std::mutex mtx;
  //std::condition_variable ccv;

  bool stop_thread = false;
  auto th1 = std::thread([&](){ while(true){ WakeConditionVariable(&cv); if(stop_thread) return; }});
  //auto th1 = std::thread([&](){ while(true){ ccv.notify_one(); if(stop_thread) return; }});

  const int64_t n = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
  auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for (int64_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&Signal);
    //  SleepConditionVariableSRW(&cv, &Signal, INFINITE, 0);
    //ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&Signal);
    
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
      SleepConditionVariableCS (&cv, &cs, INFINITE);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
    
    //std::unique_lock lk(mtx);
    //ccv.wait(lk);
  }
  auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
  stop_thread = true; th1.join();
  double nSec = 1e-6 * std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();
  printf("%.3lf calls/sec\n", n / nSec);
  
  return 0;
}
```

`std::condition_variable` is a good 20% slower.

Bottom line : if you don't need recursion/you have low contention (no `Try..` shenanigans for `SRW`), go with `SRW` (with [NtCreateKeyedEvent](http://locklessinc.com/articles/keyed_events/) special sauce), otherwise use `CS`.

---- EDIT ----

An other nice tool to consider (it's actually needed in my sample program !) is C++20's `std::latch` which can be "abused" into a "cooperative `WakeOnAddress()`" :

```cpp
std::latch mainCanBeAwakened{1};

BOOL WINAPI CtrlHandler(DWORD ctl){
  ...
    case CTRL_C_EVENT:  mainCanBeAwakened.wait(); // user typing faster than light ?
       WakeConditionVariable(&Signal); return TRUE;
  ...
}

int main(){

  ...  
  EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    mainCanBeAwakened.count_down(); // call twice (> mainCanBeAwakened.n) for UB !
    SleepConditionVariableCS (&Signal, &cs, INFINITE);
  LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
  ...
}
```

`main()` has to initialize, start workers, .. and wait for `Cntl-C` last. If it takes time doing that, a `Cntl-C` can come before the condition variable is Sleeped on, and the `WakeConditionVariable()` would have no effect on the `main()` thread. So the `CtrlHandler()` needs to know that the CV is "altered" (Sleeped on by `main()`), said differently : it needs to "`WakeOnAddress(CV)`".

As you can see above, this can be done very economically (resources & code) using a `std::latch` (which is even lighter than `std::barrier`) in the absence of `WakeOnAddress` & `SynchronizationBarrier` (available in Windows 8+) : `InitializeSynchronizationBarrier(2)` / `EnterSynchronizationBarrier` in both threads / `DeleteSynchronizationBarrier`.

---- EDIT ----

As per Alex's answer, you can further drop `CV` and `CS` ! (on Win7 in particular)

I don't think it can possibly get lighter than a **naked** ***exclusive*** ***Slim*** RW lock.

It is wiser, though, to let down the `latch` if you have a dozen locks juggled in a lively thread pool.

Comment: In MSVC, `std::latch` / `std:;barrier` / `std::semaphore` will use `std::atomic::wait`, which will turn into `WaitOnAddress` on Win8+ and `SRWLOCK` + `CONDITION_VARIABLE` on Win7

Comment: @Alex: you're exactly right. I just traced back `std:latch` (`include/atomic`) to the beginning of `xatomic_wait.h` in VS19 (`__std_atomic_`* class & functions, starting line 22). It clearly says : `WaitOnAddress` or fallback to `SRWLOCK` and `CONDITION_VARIABLE` (line 41). It's a no-brainer than : `std::latch/barrier` all the way (much nicer syntax, and safer with destructors & all), unless profiling says otherwise.

Comment: I've participated in the implementation of MSVC [`atomic::wait`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/593) and [`latch`, etc](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/1057) so I know :-) Indeed, C++ facilities provide higher abstraction level, and are also portable.

Comment: Oh ! So you're the "mature developers who care about bloat/RAII/thread safety/.." and you also came here to cover the "1% of code or less" case I mention to Ted in the  comments above !! Than you for proving me right when I commented "I expect no answer, but hey, you never know !" :))